# AWS - Iniciar Segunda Instância Via Cloudwatch

Tags: expressões-lambda, amazon-aws

Olá, eu tenho um cenário com 2 instâncias, em um "load balance no iis - Windows Server", porém na maior parte do tempo, apenas uma instância aguenta a carga.

Portanto, o cliente me solicitou, para manter a segunda instância desligada e startar ela apenas quando a primeira instância atingir 90% de uso de CPU.

Verifiquei e via EC2-Load Balance, ou CloudWatch, eu só tenho a opção de subir uma AMI da primeira instância (instância onde foi detectado o alto uso de CPU), mas uma AMI não atende este cenário visto que são instâncias um pouco diferentes.

Teria alguma forma, talvez via LAMBDA, para, quando ocorrer o evento (USO de CPU alto), eu startar remotamente a segunda instância?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Seria mais simples criar um auto-scaling grup para a segunda instancia com o minimo de 0 e maximo de 1, mudando em reacao ao alarme. A função funcionaria também, mas dá mais trabalho.